Matplotlib: Add image in top left corner of figure
I tried various methods found online but can't add an image at the correct location in the top left corner of my figure.
Here's one on my attempts, where I try to set exact the size of the generated figure in pixels, and then add a 48x48 px image in top left corner. Issues:

The figures are not created with the chosen pixel size
On the X axis, where the origin is left, I need to offset by 34 pixels to get the image near to left border, which makes no sense to me.
On the Y axis, the image is also badly placed, mostly because the size is not as expected.

Why is the code below failing?
How can I achieve what I want?
import matplotlib.pylab as plt                               # Plot
from PIL import Image                                        # Add background image
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, OffsetImage # Add background image

def plot_image(w, h):
  px         = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']           
  fig,ax     = plt.subplots(figsize=(w*px, h*px))

  image_path = '......../The Simpsons 48x48.png'
  image_data = Image.open(image_path)
  image_box  = OffsetImage(image_data, zoom=1)
  anno_box   = AnnotationBbox(image_box, xy=(34,h-48), xycoords='figure pixels', frameon=False)
  ax.add_artist(anno_box)

  plt.text(0.5, 0.5, f'Requested: {w}x{h}')
  plt.text(0.5, 0.4, 'Obtained: 579x455' if w==640 else
                     'Obtained: 759x561' if w==800 else 
                     'Obtained: 960x711' )
  plt.show()

plot_image( 640, 480)
plot_image( 800, 600)
plot_image(1024, 768)


Results:



Image used:


Are you using a notebook?  When you show in a notebook the figure is automatically resized to fit around the artists on it.  This is equivalent to passing bbox_inches='tight' when you call savefig.  It is possible to turn that off in a notebook, but I just tried replacing plt.show() in your example with plt.savefig(f'simpson_test{w}x{h}.png') and they all came out the right size.
I have not understood why the positioning is strange with AnnotationBbox, but a simpler way is figimage:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                              # Plot
from PIL import Image                                        # Add background image

def plot_image(w, h):
  px         = 1/plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']           
  fig,ax     = plt.subplots(figsize=(w*px, h*px))

  image_path = 'simpson.png'
  image_data = Image.open(image_path)
  fig.figimage(image_data, yo=h-48)

  plt.text(0.5, 0.5, f'Requested: {w}x{h}')
  plt.savefig(f'simpson_test{w}x{h}.png')

plot_image( 640, 480)
plot_image( 800, 600)
plot_image(1024, 768)





I am using VS Code. What do you use?
I tried using PyCharm but it doesn't find the libraries
import matplotlib.pylab as plt                               # Plot
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Grrr. Not only VS Code doesn't display the size correctly, it also fails to position Homer correctly.

Alright I reinstalled matplotlib from PyCharm (Why do I have to do that?) When I run the code, It opens a window titled "Figure 1" that is also displaying a totally erroneous picture. These tools seem so ancient and basic. Can't even display a picture properly? Really? Reminds me of my days where the only possible output from the mainframe was paper. :-( Any Python IDE that can display images correctly? Now PyCharm can run my code but still not yours. Gtk-Message: 12:49:45.182: Failed to load module "xapp-gtk3-module"

figimage() seems to do a fine job. Thank you. I can't believe I wasted all that time crafting an image that is not the actual result. I'll do a few more tests and mark your replay as the answer.

I’m afraid I don’t really use an IDE, I just run my scripts from the command line.

I only just noticed this example uses pylab.  That is not encouraged so I've updated the import to use pyplot.

It's all about understanding the size of the image. Ensure first that the figure size is set correctly in pixels and then correctly place the image in the top left corner using AnnotationBbox. Here is how you should do this:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, OffsetImage

def plot_image(w, h):
    px = 1 / plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']  
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w * px, h * px))

    image_path = r"C:\Users\serge.degossondevare\Downloads\homer.png"  
    image_data = Image.open(image_path)

    image_box = OffsetImage(image_data, zoom=1)
    anno_box = AnnotationBbox(image_box, xy=(0, 1), xycoords='axes fraction', 
                              box_alignment=(0, 1), frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(anno_box)

    plt.text(0.5, 0.5, f'Requested: {w}x{h}', ha='center', va='center')
    plt.text(0.5, 0.4, f'Obtained: {int(fig.bbox.width)}x{int(fig.bbox.height)}', ha='center', va='center')

    ax.set_axis_off()

    plt.show()

plot_image(640, 480)
plot_image(800, 600)
plot_image(1024, 768)

which gives you



If you want the Homer-image to be proportionally shrunk to the canvas:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib.offsetbox import AnnotationBbox, OffsetImage

def plot_image(w, h, image_path):
    px = 1 / plt.rcParams['figure.dpi']
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(w * px, h * px))

    image_data = Image.open(image_path)
    
    zoom_factor = min(w / image_data.width, h / image_data.height) * 0.1  

    image_box = OffsetImage(image_data, zoom=zoom_factor)
    anno_box = AnnotationBbox(image_box, xy=(0, 1), xycoords='axes fraction', 
                              box_alignment=(0, 1), frameon=False)
    ax.add_artist(anno_box)

    plt.text(0.5, 0.5, f'Requested: {w}x{h}', ha='center', va='center')
    plt.text(0.5, 0.4, f'Obtained: {int(fig.bbox.width)}x{int(fig.bbox.height)}', ha='center', va='center')

    ax.set_axis_off()

    plt.show()

image_path = r"C:\Users\serge.degossondevare\Downloads\homer.png"
plot_image(640, 480, image_path)
plot_image(800, 600, image_path)
plot_image(1024, 768, image_path)

which gives



Then it is up to you to scale.

Thank you.
I still have to learn a lot about that AnnotationBbox. However:

1- The images above are not as expected. The size is off.
 for the 800x600 image.

2- The inserted image is not flush.

Then you should post what you expect.

Sorry about the formatting. I have no idea how to format when replying. If formatting is at all possible.

I updated with an alternative that scales proportinally to the canvas

Sadly, the update still doesn't create images at the expected resolution, or set homer flush to the edges.

Also Homer seems to be added at about 85x85 px in size

Alright, it seems the issue is my IDE does not display the generated images correctly, as pointed out by RuthC. What IDE do you use, where you don't have to save the image to view it correctly?

@Chris I think Serge has the same problem - if you inspect the images posted within this answer they are not the correct size.

Yes that's what I tried to emphasize by providing the HTML of the graphs uploaded by Serge. Using AnnotationBbox doesn't position the image properly and doesn't size the inserted image properly. Very disappointing for such a mature library.
And very disappointing that Python IDEs can't even display the created images properly. That seems like such a basic feature.
